# Loopback: What does this mean "Domain.app.models.Group.create();" in loopback?

Tags: mongodb, model, loopback

I have two models named : Domain and Group.
I'm not able to understand what the following code does

```
 Domain.app.models.Group.create({
                      "name": groupItem.name,
                      "type": groupItem.type,
                      "refId": groupItem.id
                    }, function(err, group) {
                     // some work here
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you create models in your `common/models` directory and then each script receives the model as an argument of the exports function.

One thing to notice is that Loopback app variable is linked to each model with the property `app`. So, when you call `Domain.app` you are retrieving the whole Loopback app object, and upon that object, you fetch other models in the application, namely Group in your example.

It's a best practice to declare a `var` for each model of interest per function in your script and operate with them after that. For example:

```
var Group = Domain.app.models.Group;
Group.create(...);
```

Now, the last part is involved with what properties the Group model inherits from its father `PersistentModel`, in your example the `create` function [(1)](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Creating-updating-and-deleting-data.html)[(2)](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-create). In this case, the `create` property stores the input data in the DataSource attached to your model. This datasource association with the model is declared in `server/model-config.json` and the `boot` function in `server/server.js` is in charge of reading this file and execute the pertinent routines to do the actual model attachment.